# Is there a shortcut for computing the sum of the same integer but with different divisors?

Tags: polynomials, computational-complexity

When expanding a factorised polynomial expression, the x^1 term will be a sum of the products of every linear constant but without a single constant. ie: When expanding (x+a)(x+b)(x+c)(x+d), the x^1 term has a coefficient that is abc+abd+acd+bcd. This kind of calculation feels like one that has a tricksy shortcut using algebra, number theory, or linear algebra, but I can't think of any way to make it faster. The only thing I thought might have some merit is computing z=abcd then calculating z/d + z/c + z/b + z/a.

Is there some kind of trick or workaround that allows one to find this coefficient that is better than just working it out straightforwardly?

Comment: "...computing z=abcd then calculating z/d + z/c + z/b + z/a..." : I don't see how you can improve on that approach.

Comment: would that be an improvement from abc+abd+acd+bcd

Comment: Yes, I think so, because (assuming that $~a,b,c,d~$ are all integers) all of the fractions turn out to be integers, so the computations are easier.  You only do the *overall* multiplication once.

Comment: thank you! Just checking... factoring out the Z like Z * (1/a + 1/b + 1/c + 1/d) would be slower because 1/integer is ugly and would require many more steps to compute?

Comment: Possibly.  In this case, I suspect not, because it is unnecessary to express (for example) $~(1/d).~$  Note that (for example) $~\dfrac{a \times b \times c \times d}{d}~$ is guaranteed to be an integer, assuming that $~a,b,c,d~$ are all integers.  So, you never have to be concerned with reciprocals; all of the divisions *come out even*.